# MongoDB-mongoose high cpu use when saving large documents in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-ec2, mongoose

I'm developing a pixel tracking app hosted on EC2, which is called on every request of a video ad, so it tracks when it started, completed and if a click action was made. I'm using node.js with express as I wanted to respond as fast as possible and mongoDB/Mongoose since it is like a server log structure. I receive requests almost every millisecond. But when storing documents to the collection, it takes a huge amount of CPU almost 100% and in the end node.js launches the error:

```
GET /pixel/impression/ad1 200 1ms
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I think it's the mongoose operation the one who's taking most of the cpu as I remove parts, it never hangs.

On app.js I have:

```
var hostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ip: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  metricCount: {
    impression: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    clicks:  { type: Number, default: 0 },
    complete: { type: Number, default: 0 }
  },
  impressionHosts: [hostSchema],
  clicksHosts: [hostSchema],
  completeHosts: [hostSchema]
});

var Order = mongoose.model('order', orderSchema);
var Host = mongoose.model('host', hostSchema);
```

and the the express get method:

```
app.get('/pixel/:metric/:campaignName', function(req, res){

  var campaignName = req.params.campaignName;
  var metrica = req.params.metric;

  Order.find({name: campaignName}, function(err, doc){
    newMet = {};
    newMet[metrica] = 1;

    var incomingHost = new Host({ip: req.ip});
    if(doc.length<1){
         insertNewElement(campaignName, newMet, metrica, incomingHost);
       }else {
         updateElement(doc[0], metrica, incomingHost);
         }
  });
res.end(pixel, 'binary');
});
```

When I comment the "updateElement" function, node.js performs "perfectly". Here these functions:

```
function updateElement(doc, metrica, incomingHost){
    doc.metricCount[metrica]+=1;
      doc[metrica+'Hosts'].push(incomingHost);
      doc.save(function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
          //console.log('Record Updated')
      });
}

function insertNewElement(campaignName, newMet, metrica, incomingHost) {
  new Order({ name : campaignName, metricCount: newMet }).save(function(err, doc){
         if (err) res.json(err);
           doc[metrica+'Hosts'].push(incomingHost);
           doc.save(function(err){
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
              }
               // console.log('new record added '+ doc.name);
            });
         });
}
```

I believe the problem resides when pushing a new host, since there are a lot, although, as I'm not expert on mongoDB I don't know how to improve that method, if that's causing the issues. Most of my code has been tweaked thanks to the mongo documentation and research.

How can I make the update faster and avoid the memory error on nodejs?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using any indexes on the collection? Due to the lack of document level locking in mongo, the entire db gets locked on a write. You can speed this up by ensuring that no indexes need to get updated in the same shot.

Comment: No, not really, well I believe that I'm only "using" the _id: index by default. Actually I thought it had to do with the lack of index when searching something, but I think (as you) that that won't help any further. Maybe there is a problem on the doc[metrica+'Hosts'].push(...), since that can be a huge array of documents. What do you think?

Comment: If your document is constantly growing, its likely forcing it to be reallocated on disk to keep it from fragmenting. I'll detail more information in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a document in mongo, it allocates a portion of disk space to the document, with enough padding to accommodate document an estimated growth. If the document size exceeds the allocated space, mongo needs to move and reallocate new space for the document. This will keep happening as your document is growing.

To avoid this, you will need to pre-allocate space. You do this by filling enough data into the document where mongo will allocate enough space to fit the max document size.

In your case, when you first insert a new document, you will add enough host sub documents, to replicate your larger documents. After you insert that document, you can remove the hosts sub documents and insert the correct records.

Now, this is not perfect. Mongo does not support transactions, so you may have an update hitting the document before the insert process cleans up the pre-allocated document.

Also with mongo, keep your field names as short as possible. Mongo stores the full field name as part of the document whenever its used. While this may not seem like much, it can account for a significant amount of disk space in large collections.

Comment: Thank you datasage, the solution you suggest is awesome, since in my case the length of the dataset can be computed in the beginning. Now, for an app like this, where the write takes longer than every request (1ms/request and 300ms write) should be better to switch to an in memory database like redis? and store every something to the disk?

Comment: You are going to have to hit a disk somewhere for persistence. The longer the delay between storing the value in memory and persisting it to disk, the greater chance data will be lost in the event of a failure. Other things you can try is to optimize IO with raid, and if cost effective, use SSD instances.

Comment: Another option is to write data to an RDBMS system and then batch process it later into your document. You will get transactions and wont run into the pre-allocation problem. NoSQL is not always a good choice for every problem.

Comment: Thank you @datasage. I think I'll be switching to a RDBMS, since I don't see any better option for appending a new document faster to the hosts list.